# How do I make these "hint" looking things in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

I am making a Roblox game and am trying to make these things that look like Hints, except they are in the bottom right corner of your screen and much smaller. How do you make these: [image: the hint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a notification. You can access it by StarterGui:SetCore.

`game:GetService("StarterGui"):SetCore("SendNotification", {Title = "Obby", Text = "+300 Coins"})`

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/StarterGui/SetCore