# Roblox notification

Tags: notifications, roblox

So I wanted to make a notification on Roblox that sends the player who joined a notification with their profile picture and username like this
"Welcome username"

I don't know how to do lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67940963/2860267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalScript goes into StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")
game:GetService("StarterGui"):SetCore("SendNotification", {
    Title = "Weclome!";
    Text = "Welcome, " .. players.LocalPlayer.DisplayName;
    Icon = "rbxthumb://type=AvatarHeadShot&id=" .. players.LocalPlayer.UserId .. "&w=180&h=180 true";
    Duration = 5
})
```